# SQL Server trigger's cursor is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, cursor

I created a cursor inside a trigger and it is not working properly. Please help me fix it

```
Create trigger Posts_Raw_To_Queue_Trigger  ON SendNotificationPostsRaw FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PostID uniqueidentifier  
DECLARE @UserID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @ProfID int
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @CreationTime  datetime
DECLARE @SpecialityID int

SELECT @ProfID= ProfessionalID,@Email= Email from Professionals where UserID=@UserID
SELECT @PostID = I.PostID,@UserID = I.UserID ,@CreationTime =I.CreationTime  FROM INSERTED I

DECLARE post_relation_cursor CURSOR FOR select CategoryId  from PostCategoryRelations  where PostId=@PostID;

OPEN post_relation_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM post_relation_cursor INTO @SpecialityID 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       INSERT INTO SendNotificationPostsQueue (UserID,PostID,SpecialityID,TemplateID,CreationTime,SendTime,JSONParameters) Values(@UserID,@PostID,1,1,'04/11/2013','04/11/2013','')

       FETCH NEXT FROM post_relation_cursor INTO @SpecialityID;
END;
CLOSE post_relation_cursor;
DEALLOCATE post_relation_cursor;

END
```

If I remove cursor and insert dummy values into `SendNotificationPostsQueue`, it works. So there is problem with my cursor... Please tell me why cursor is not working?

Comment: what is your now i mean what happen if u use cursor. what result it give

Comment: Looks like you are assuming there in only one row in the inserted table. This is wrong. Don't know if that is the cause of your "not working", but it is wrong in any case.

Comment: I am using Sql Server Web Admin, So I cannot see any errors. I cannot debug

Comment: what should I do to fix it to work with multiple rows

Comment: What do you mean with "not working properly"? Error? Infinite execution? No rows inserted? Wrong rows inserted?

Comment: unfortuanetly, I cannot debug or see any errors. I am using web tool

Comment: so how u know its not working....

Comment: I check the table and I see insertion doesnt happen. thats how I understand it is not working

Comment: so, the user inserts a row into the SendNotificationPostsRaw table, I will check how many specialities that row has and do many insertions into SendNotificationPostsQueue  as needed. it post has 5 specialities, then I will do 5 insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you need to use a cursor at all and would be better off not using one in almost all cases.  Simply replace the body of your trigger (the part between begin and end) with a standard insert:

```
INSERT INTO SendNotificationPostsQueue (UserID,PostID,SpecialityID,TemplateID,CreationTime,SendTime,JSONParameters)
SELECT
    i.UserID,
    i.PostID,
    1,
    1,
    '04/11/2013', -- Might want i.CreationTime or current_timestamp
    '04/11/2013',
    ''
FROM INSERTED i
    -- possibly want "LEFT JOIN Professionals p on i.UserID = p.UserID" here to grab other info
```

Note how I am not using the `values` clause of an insert which can only insert one row. I'm putting a select statement as part of the insert, thus inserting as many rows as the select returns. This means that we don't need to use a cursor, and don't need a bunch of variables to power the cursor.

One issue with your current code, as @automatic has mentioned, is that you're assuming INSERTED only holds one row. If it has more than one, then you'll throw an error when you try to assign a column to a variable.

For reasons of elegance, maintainability, and performance, I strongly urge you to abandon this cursor and run a simple insert (since that's all that your cursor is doing anyway).

Comment: well, I have to loop an entire table, I need to have a cursor

Comment: Can we bet on that? SQL and RDBMS systems work with sets of data. It is very rarely necessary to process rows one at a time. I see nothing in your trigger that suggests this to be one of those occasions.

Comment: well, my problem is I sometimes have to insert 3 rows if the post has 3 SpecialityID

Comment: Is SpecialtyID in Professionals? Simply join INSERTED to Professionals as I've left in code comments. I think you should come up with the select statement that gets the data you need and then just use that same select in an insert.

Comment: I have a SpecialityTable seperatly

Comment: I dont get it my friend, I dont understand your logic. Lets say I have 3 tables, Post, Speciality and PostSpecialityRelation. If I dont have a cursor, how can I insert 3-4 rows with a single insert ? I dont understand this. I am sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28030/discussion-between-tim-lehner-and-borsel)

Comment: @Borsel Here is a good article about common (miss)usage of Cursors and how to replace them with Set-Based operations: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem is here -

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Posts_Raw_To_Queue_Trigger 

    ON SendNotificationPostsRaw
    -- for view
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    -- OR
    -- for table
    AFTER INSERT

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
          @PostID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        , @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        , @ProfID INT
        , @Email NVARCHAR(100)
        , @CreationTime DATETIME
        , @SpecialityID INT

    SELECT  @ProfID = ProfessionalID
        ,   @Email = Email
    FROM Professionals
    WHERE UserID = @UserID

    -- this posible return invalid result (random record from inserted sequence)
    SELECT  @PostID = I.PostID
        ,   @UserID = I.UserID
        ,   @CreationTime = I.CreationTime
    FROM INSERTED I

    DECLARE post_relation_cursor CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT CategoryID
        FROM dbo.PostCategoryRelations
        WHERE PostId = @PostID;

    OPEN post_relation_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM post_relation_cursor INTO @SpecialityID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO SendNotificationPostsQueue (
                UserID
            ,   PostID
            ,   SpecialityID
            ,   TemplateID
            ,   CreationTime
            ,   SendTime
            ,   JSONParameters
        )
        SELECT
                 @UserID
             ,   @PostID
             ,   @SpecialityID --- !!!
             ,   1
             ,   '04/11/2013'
             ,   '04/11/2013'
             ,   ''


        FETCH NEXT FROM post_relation_cursor INTO @SpecialityID;

    END;

    CLOSE post_relation_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE post_relation_cursor;

END
```

---

**Update**

If I understand you correctly, the business logic must be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Posts_Raw_To_Queue_Trigger 

    ON dbo.SendNotificationPostsRaw
    [INSTEAD OF]/[AFTER] INSERT

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
          @PostID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        , @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        , @ProfID INT
        , @Email NVARCHAR(100)
        , @CreationTime DATETIME
        , @SpecialityID INT

    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT
              i.PostID
            , i.UserID
            , ProfID = p.ProfessionalID
            , p.Email
            , i.CreationTime
            , pcr.CategoryID
        FROM INSERTED i
        JOIN dbo.Professionals p ON i.UserID = p.UserID
        JOIN dbo.PostCategoryRelations pcr ON i.PostID = pcr.PostID

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
          @PostID 
        , @UserID 
        , @ProfID 
        , @Email
        , @CreationTime 
        , @SpecialityID 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbo.SendNotificationPostsQueue 
        (
              UserID
            , PostID
            , SpecialityID
            , TemplateID
            , CreationTime
            , SendTime
            , JSONParameters
        )
        SELECT
              @UserID
            , @PostID
            , @SpecialityID
            , 1
            , @CreationTime
            , @CreationTime
            , ''

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
              @PostID 
            , @UserID 
            , @ProfID 
            , @Email
            , @CreationTime 
            , @SpecialityID 

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

Comment: I couldnt see the difference. would you tell me the problem. thanks for your time my friend.